# Ethereum performance when fetching transactions from blocks

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, private-blockchain

I need to fetch the completed transactions from the ethereum blockchain ledger. At the moment I am retrieving individual blocks in order to fetch the transactions using `web3.eth.getBlock` synchronously. However this is taking a long time (around 25 secs to fetch transactions from 40 blocks in my case where the nodes are deployed on Azure). I understand that I could asynchronously fetch the transactions using multiple threads and then arrange them based on timestamp. But is there another way to optimize performance, so that transactions could be fetched synchronously as well?